# How to add message-bundle to SpringBoot-JSF application

Tags: spring-boot, jsf

I have a spring-jsf integration app. When I try to get messages from resource-bundle at faces-config.xml, it runs with problem.Here is my faces-config:

```
    <application>
    <el-resolver>com.itpeac.common.web.faces.ConversationAwareElResolver</el-resolver>
    <message-bundle>com.itpeac.common.web.util.MessageBundle</message-bundle>
    <resource-bundle>
        <base-name>com.itpeac.common.web.util.MessageBundle</base-name>
        <var>msg</var>
    </resource-bundle>

</application>
```

Here is my error:

```
Critical error during deployment:
```

com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:453)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.itpeac.common.web.util.MessageBundle.handleGetObject(MessageBundle.java:34)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getObject(ResourceBundle.java:441)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getString(ResourceBundle.java:407)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceManager.getLocalePrefix(ResourceManager.java:608)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceManager.findResource(ResourceManager.java:188)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.createViewResource(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:123)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.createViewResource(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:72)
    at javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.createViewResource(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:124)
    at javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.createViewResource(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:124)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultResourceResolver.resolveUrl(DefaultResourceResolver.java:80)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.init(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:170)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.createFaceletFactory(ApplicationAssociate.java:895)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.initializeFacelets(ApplicationAssociate.java:332)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.getCompiler(ApplicationAssociate.java:415)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.process(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:251)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:441)
    ... 10 common frames omitted

2018-11-01 18:08:49.406 ERROR 17232 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener]

java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:453)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:227)
    ... 9 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.itpeac.common.web.util.MessageBundle.handleGetObject(MessageBundle.java:34)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getObject(ResourceBundle.java:441)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getString(ResourceBundle.java:407)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceManager.getLocalePrefix(ResourceManager.java:608)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceManager.findResource(ResourceManager.java:188)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.createViewResource(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:123)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.createViewResource(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:72)
    at javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.createViewResource(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:124)
    at javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.createViewResource(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:124)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultResourceResolver.resolveUrl(DefaultResourceResolver.java:80)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.init(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:170)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.createFaceletFactory(ApplicationAssociate.java:895)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.initializeFacelets(ApplicationAssociate.java:332)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.getCompiler(ApplicationAssociate.java:415)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.process(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:251)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:441)
    ... 10 common frames omitted

Comment: Hi, please debug **what** is null.... in what line of code etc...

Comment: resourcesUtil.getProperty(key);is return null

Comment: So the key is not found in there?

Comment: in my message bundle class i have a method Enumeration<String> getKeys() is return null.